# .Net EntityFramework Mysql при запросе дважды указывается база данных

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

При выборки данных из таблицы Mysql "customer" Entity дважды указывает наименование базы данных "etity.etity.customer" в итоге приходит исключение, помогите понять, где нужно сделать корректировку в настройках, искал подобную проблему в Google ничего не нашел, я впервые с этим Fraemwork связался вот код:

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            <!--<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>-->
            <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.22.0" newVersion="8.0.22.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Protobuf" publicKeyToken="a7d26565bac4d604" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.13.0.0" newVersion="3.13.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="K4os.Compression.LZ4.Streams" publicKeyToken="2186fa9121ef231d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.6.0" newVersion="1.2.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="BouncyCastle.Crypto" publicKeyToken="0e99375e54769942" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.6.0" newVersion="1.8.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="LessonsContext" connectionString="password=T@#*HyWU3q6#3mW;server=localhost;user id=zennolab;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=etity" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lessons
{
  class Program
  {    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var customers = GetCustomersEf();
      foreach(var customer in customers)
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"Id: {customer.CustomerId} Name {customer.CustomerName}");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static List<customer> GetCustomersEf()
    {
      var context = new LessonsModel();
      List<customer> customers = context.customer.ToList();
      return customers;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

После выполнения Code First from the database созданному class "customer" присваивается атрибут [Table("etity.customer")] имя базы нужно удалить.

Comment: Спасибо, что оставляете ответы к своим же вопросам когда находите решение. Мне всегда кажется, что это показывает, что человек неравнодушен к сайту и хочет здесь остаться. Можно небольшой совет, чтобы облегчить вливание в коммьюнити? У вас в вопросе код прикреплён картинкой и это неудобно по многим причинам (неудобно смотреть с сотовых, поиск по картинке не работает), поэтому очень часто за код в картинке ставят минус вопросу. Старайтесь избегать по возможности. Код - это текст, вставляйте его текстом. Ошибка - это текст, её тоже нужно вставялять как текст.